# How do I set node definition from docker plugin?

Tags: rundeck

I try to set Docker containers as node with the following **Custom Mapping** :

```
hostname.selector=docker:IPAddress
node.name.selector=docker:Name
username.selector=root
osFamily.selector=Docker
ssh-authentication=password
ssh-password-storage-path=keys/${node.hostname}/${node.username}
node.ssh-authentication.selector=password
docker-shell.default=bash
```

I alway get this error message :

```
Failed: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "xxxxxx". Make sure your resource definitions and credentials are up to date.
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the Docker node executor. Project Settings > Edit Configuration > Default Node Executor tab (select "docker-container-node-executor") and save it.

Comment: I forget to thank you for your reply, it have worked fine. 
But as I need to mix containers and reals servers I can't fix the default node executor for all the project...

Comment: You can create a script calling this endpoint using CURL https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#project-configuration or using RD CLI https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/ (rd projects configure set -h) against your containers/servers. Hope it helps!